# why is friction acting towards the centre in a level curved road?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

We all know that friction is a force that opposes motion and is applied in the opposite direction of motion, but in a leveled curved road it becomes the centripetal force and pulls towards the center. Why?

Comment: By definition, circular motion requires a force that constantly points toward the center of the circle.  If the friction force on the car pointed in any other direction, the path would not be circular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Newton's first law, in the absence of an external force, a car would move along a straight line. When the front wheels of the car are turned to follow a curved road, the car is blocked from moving straight by the friction, serving as that external force.

So, we can say that, if it was not for the friction force, opposing the natural straight movement of the car, the car would not be able to turn or stay on a curved road.

The direction of the friction force is normal to the wheels and their trajectory. So, we can say that the friction force acts along the radius of the trajectory curve, pointing to its center, which makes it a centripetal force.

Answer (score 2):

Friction doesn't necessarily oppose motion. It only opposes *relative motion*, we could call it *sliding*.

- Imagine driving on ice and trying to turn. The cars wheels may turn but the ice is too slippery so the car just continues straight ahead. The turned wheel simply slide over the surface.
- If you instead drive in asphalt, then a friction appears which will prevent you from continuing to slide. The friction will be perpendicular to the turned wheel, because this is the direction in which sliding is to be prevented.

Therefore a not straight ahead friction appears.

If you continue and keep the turning, then the sideways friction component causes a circular motion.

Comment: what's asphalt?

Comment: but i mean the car is going straight, so friction should be towards the backward direction, or even opposite of sliding. then why is friction = sliding?

Comment: @DakshMiglani The car is not going straight if the road is curved. Then is following the road along this curved path. By asphalt I just mean the ground/road.

Comment: why does the car even slide outwards?

Comment: @DakshMiglani I am not sure what you mean. The car follows the curved path because it follows the road. It doesn't slide out.